# Cтатический внутренний (вложенный) класс имеет доступ ко всем полям и методам внешнего класса?

Tags: java

Cтатический внутренний (вложенный) класс имеет доступ ко всем полям и методам внешнего класса?

Я предполагаю, что внутренний класс имеет доступ только к статическим метода и полям. Так ли это?
ЭТО ВОПРОС ИЗ ТЕСТА. и сначала выглядит так:

Утверждение: статический внутренний (вложенный) класс имеет доступ ко всем полям и методам внешнего класса
1.Верно
2.Не верно

- Поэтому можно отвечать просто 1 или 2

Comment: Посмотрите как я исправил ваш вопрос - в текущем виде он хорош, полезен и соберёт плюсы с ответами вместо минусов. Старайтесь примерно так оформлять вопросы, пожалуйста)

Comment: Лично вам хочу подчеркнуть что это вопрос из теста и я хотел максимально передать условия задачи (а может и неоднозначность ответа) и главное ели будут искать ответ на тест с такой формулировкой то можно найти намного быстрее!!!Верните пожалуйста!!!

Comment: @user293633 Если это из теста (и вы его никак не пытались решить самостоятельно), высокая вероятность что его закроют. Даже есть такая формулировка про учебные вопросы в тревогах.

Comment: @user293633 Stackoverflow - это база знаний, а не ответов на тесты.

Comment: @user293633, основную формулировку я не менял. Но в том виде, в котором вы вопрос опубликовали вопрос просто обречён. Будут минусы, закрытие и автоматическое удаление системой. Если вы хотите делиться полезной информацией, то надо учитывать и возможность сохранения оной. В данном случае тут даже не буду поднимать тему того, что мы на сайте БД знаний собираем, а не сборник шпаргалок. Если вам не нравится что-то из правил или обычаев сайта - поднимите вопрос на [мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/) - возможно у вас получится изменить общее мнение.

Answer (score 2):

Да, т.к. класс статический - он может быть создан без создания экземпляра внешнего класса.

```
//создание экземпляра статического внутреннего класса НЕ требует создания экземпляра внешнего класса.
new Outer.InnerStaticClass();

//создание экземпляра НЕстатического внутреннего класса требует создания экземпляра внешнего класса.
new Outer().new InnerStaticClass();
```

Засим доступа к нестатическим членам внешнего класса у вложенного класса быть не может в виду отсутствия ссылки на его (внешнего класса) экземпляр.

Comment: А для статического класса разве нужно писать new?

Comment: @TimurMukhortov, да. Невозможно создать экземпляр класса без этого ключевого слова безотносительно типа класса. Таков синтаксис языка.

Comment: не так сформулировал вопрос. Я не со всем понимаю для чего делать инстанс статик класса в вашем ответе

Comment: @TimurMukhortov, ну, я типа показал, что при создании статического внутреннего класса при создании экземпляра не вызывается конструктор внешнего класса. А для нестатического - вызывается.

Comment: вопрос немного о другом...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Понял. Согласен. Вы можете обратиться к внутреннему статик классу через имя внешнего класса. Читаю вопрос «Статический внутренний (вложенный) класс имеет доступ ко всем полям и методам внешнего класса». А как вы обратитесь к внешнему классу из статик класса, если у вас внешний класс не создан. Вы же создаёте экземпляр внутреннего статического класса. Или я не прав?

Comment: я предполагал что речь может идет в вопросе о чем-то тип:       public class Task {
    private int fild;
    private static int staticFild;
    public void method(){ System.out.println("Method"); }
    public static void staticMethod() { System.out.println("staticMethod"); }
    public static class Test {
        int x = staticFild;
        int y = fild; //ошибка
        public void testMethod() {
            method();//ошибка
            staticMethod();
        }
    }
}

Comment: @TimurMukhortov, да, всё верно - нет экземпляра внешнего класса - не к кому обращаться.

Comment: @user293633 а чего вы не можете написать это и проверить? Вам уже написали что и как можно

Comment: @ Timur Mukhortov Возможно есть какие-то тонкости о которых я не знаю ...

Answer (score 2):

> Утверждение: статический внутренний (вложенный) класс имеет доступ ко
>   всем полям и методам внешнего класса 1.Верно 2.Не верно

Не верно, вы не можете обратиться из внутреннего статического класса, так как вам нужна ссылка на объект внешнего класса.

> Я предполагаю, что внутренний класс имеет доступ только к статическим
>   метода и полям. Так ли это?

Да, это так. Если вы про статические поля или методы внешнего класса пишите.

Comment: Спасибо, вам большое!!!

Comment: @user293633 напишите спасибо ЮриюСПБ еслиб не он ваш вопрос удалили из за формулировки и вы не получили ответа